# On convergence of particular functions in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

I'm having trouble showing the following fact:

> **Suppose** $1\le p<\infty$, $\ \varphi\in C^\infty(0,\infty)$ such that 
>   $$\varphi(s)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0, & s\leq 1/2\\
> y\in[0,1],& s\in(1/2,1) \\
> 1,& s\geq 1
> \end{cases}$$ 
>   and $v\in C^1(\mathbb R \times (0,\infty))\, \cap  W^{1,p}(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty))$  such that $v(x_1, 0) = 0$ for all $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> **Then**
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to +0}\left\| v(x_1, x_2) \varphi(x_2/\varepsilon) - v(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{W^{1,p}\left(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty)\right)} = 0
> $$

Would you please help me?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Are you sure, that condition of $v(x_1, 0)=0$ is needed? I don't see how yet

Comment: Your *recent edit* makes no sense, please be more attentive about that. And if you want to add something to your question, preferably you do it below existing content and mark it accordingly. Also, you overlooked/ignored my question above about the *origin of your problem*. Note that clear notion of the context of the problem gives an answerer more motivation to solve it, and description of the background makes the post more usefull to other readers.

Comment: Seriously, look: you have $v\in C^1(\mathbb R \times (0,\infty))$, $v\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty))$. What's that about?

Comment: @Glinka But $1/\epsilon \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0 $ in your last statement of the answer. I could not see it

Comment: Yeap, that's clearly a mistake, sorry, I'll try to fix it. In the mean time please stop ignoring my questions. What space function $v$ is from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's formulate a lemma:

> Suppose $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}\times(0,+\infty))$ and $\varphi\in C^\infty(0,+\infty)$ as in the question. Then $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\|f(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-f(x_1,x_2)\|_{L^p}=0$$

**Proof of the lemma.** Note that
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,+\infty)}|f(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-f(x_1,x_2)|^pd\mu =
$$
$$
=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,\varepsilon)}|f(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-f(x_1,x_2)|^pd\mu\ \
\leq\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,\varepsilon)}|f(x_1,x_2)|^pd\mu 
$$
And the latter goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon\to +0$, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,\varepsilon)}|f(x_1,x_2)|^pd\mu \leq\|f\|^p_{L^2(\mathbb{R}\times(0,+\infty))}<\infty$.

---

Now using this lemma we have first
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\|v(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-v(x_1,x_2)\|_{L^p}=0,$$
second
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{L^p}=0,$$
and third
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}v(x_1,x_2)\varphi'(x_2/\varepsilon)-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{L^p}\leq$$
$$
\leq
\underbrace{\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)\varphi(x_2/\varepsilon)-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{L^p}}_{=0\ \textrm{by lemma}}
+
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left\|v(x_1,x_2)\varphi'(x_2/\varepsilon)\right\|_{L^p}=
$$
$$
=
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left\|v(x_1,x_2)\varphi'(x_2/\varepsilon)\right\|_{L^p}
\leq
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left\|v(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{L^p}\cdot\sup\limits_{(0,+\infty)}\varphi'\right)=0.
$$
All these three gives us
$$
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left\| v(x_1, x_2) \varphi(x_2/\varepsilon) - v(x_1,x_2)\right\|_{W^{1,p}\left(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty)\right)} = 0
$$

Comment: thank you so much! now I think I can study by your help!

Comment: @Keverta, no problem, ask if something is unclear